# Hadoop Configuration Physical Location

Tags: hadoop

I want to ask a basic question that I couldn't find in online tutorials.

Does the hadoop config files need to be on all nodes? (NameNode, DataNode, JobTracker, and etc)

Or do they only need to reside on the user@machine where NameNode resides?

In other words, to properly set up a fully distributed cluster, do I need to replicate the config files to every single node?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right, the config files need to be on every slave.

I say just slave, because a master has usually other configurations you may want to use, which makes the configuration on the slaves a bit more verbose.

Two things that make live more easier:

- Use a NFS Mount for the configuration of the slaves
- Or use a tool that does this for you like [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/)